# Java finding one file but not another in the same location

Tags: java

```
    import java.io.*;               //Importing to read from file.
import java.util.Scanner;       //Importing Scanner class.
import java.text.DecimalFormat; //Importing DecimalFormat class.


public class StockAssessment
{
    public static void main(String[] args)  throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("Joe Williams");

        // Setting up DecimalFormat.
        DecimalFormat money = new DecimalFormat("$###.##");

        // Setting up the scanner.
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        /*
            Prompting for the file name and initalizing
            it to fileName.
        */
        System.out.print("Name of the file? ");
        String fileName = keyboard.nextLine();

        //Opening the file.
        File theFile = new File(fileName);
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(theFile);

        //Making sure the file exists.
        if (!theFile.exists())
        {
            System.out.println("========================");
            System.out.println("No transactions processed.");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        //Getting data from stock file.
        while (inputFile.hasNext())
        {
            String str = inputFile.nextLine();
            int shareAmount = inputFile.nextInt();
            double purchasePrice = inputFile.nextDouble();
            double purchCommissRate = inputFile.nextDouble();
            double salePrice = inputFile.nextDouble();
            double saleComiss = inputFile.nextDouble();
        }
        inputFile.close();

        }

    }
```

I don't understand why this code will find one file but not another if they're both in the folder that the source code is in. The code isn't fully there, I have a method waiting to be put into the code but that requires that I be able to open the file that Java currently can't find. If someone could let me know how to fix this issue that would be greatly appreciated.

---

```
Name of the file? StockData.txt
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
        at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
        at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
        at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
        at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
        at StockAssessment.main(StockAssessment.java:46)
Press any key to continue . . .
```

---

one is titled EmptyFile.txt and the other is StockData.txt. It recognizes the empty file but not Stock data

```
DELL: Dell Inc
125 25.567  0.025   28.735  0.025
MSFT: Microsoft
34.1    -15.75  0.012   15.90   0.013
GOOG: Google
56.5    58.125  0.032   67.975  0.030
IBM: IBM Corp
87.3    8.875   0.015   7.500   0.020
```

Comment: Post the error message that you are getting, and the file names.

Comment: It seems it does "recognize" the file because your program crashes while reading the STock data. Check this, or post the data on that file.

Comment: @laune I added it at the bottom

Comment: If you invent data (as you clearly have) you should heed the type, i.e., don't test with a fraction where an integer is expected. (Unless you want to stress-test your program - but it sure isn't written to survive such a test.)

Answer (score 1):

If the file is not found then it should give you

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: StockData (The system cannot find the file specified).
```

In your case the problem is somewhere.

```
        String str = inputFile.nextLine();
        int shareAmount = inputFile.nextInt();
        double purchasePrice = inputFile.nextDouble();
        double purchCommissRate = inputFile.nextDouble();
        double salePrice = inputFile.nextDouble();
        double saleComiss = inputFile.nextDouble();
```

If the requested values does not match this structure,  an InputMismatchException will be thrown.

**Update**

**For the code to work you need to change the way you have written the data inside StockData.**

```
DELL: Dell Inc 
125 
25.567 
0.025 
28.735 
0.025
```

Comment: As Ravi Thapliyal, pointed out In your StockData.txt the shareAmount is not an int for all companies. Do change that too.

Answer (score 1):

In your *StockData.txt* the `shareAmount` is not an `int` for all companies. For example,

```
MSFT: Microsoft
34.1 ...
GOOG: Google
56.5 ...
```

So, either list the amounts as an *integer* or use `nextDouble()` to read them as well.

```
String str = inputFile.nextLine();

// cast to int; 34.1 becomes 34
int shareAmount = (int) inputFile.nextDouble();
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add another nextLine to complete reading the line with the numbers.

```
while (inputFile.hasNext())  {
        String str = inputFile.nextLine();
        int shareAmount = inputFile.nextInt();
        double purchasePrice= inputFile.nextDouble();
        double purchCommissRate = inputFile.nextDouble();
        double salePrice = inputFile.nextDouble();
        double saleComiss = inputFile.nextDouble();

        inputFile.nextLine();
    }
```

Alternatively, read all lines as String

```
 while( inputFile.hasNextLine() ){
     String name = inputFile.nextLine();
     String data = inputFile.nextLine();
     Scanner ds = new Scanner( data );
     int shareAmount = ds.nextInt();
     double purchasePrice= ds.nextDouble();
     double purchCommissRate = ds.nextDouble();
     double salePrice = ds.nextDouble();
     double saleComiss = ds.nextDouble();
}
```